# Groovy containsKey function doesn't work properly

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below groovy code:

```
if (!parameters.containsKey('BUNDLE_NAME'))
    {
        echo "mandatory param"
        error ("mandatory param")
    }

    if (!parameters.containsKey('BUNDLE_VERSION'))
    {
        echo "mandatory param"
        error ("mandatory param")
    }
```

the issue is that it works for both cases, empty or not.
[image: Pipeline parameters]

From console:

```
[Pipeline] echo
mandatory param
[Pipeline] error
```

Comment: Try `echo(params.keys().inspect())` to see what's in there

Comment: argument types: () values: []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad, but a lesson for others in the future:
Pipeline code:

```
stage ("valdation"){
    steps{
        script{
            amd_distribution_check_artifacts_exists credential_id: params.DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIAL_ID, distribution_url: params.DISTRIBUTION_URL, bundle_name: params.BUNDLE_NAME, bundle_version: BUNDLE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

I had to approach the variables with lower case

```
   if (!parameters['bundle_name'])
    {
        echo "mandatory param"
        error ("mandatory param")
    }

    if (!parameters['bundle_version'])
    {
        echo "mandatory param"
        error ("mandatory param")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as your pipeline defines the parameters, you can safely assume that these keys will be there. It is only helpful against other people unknowingly deleting these from parameters, and even then the pipeline would fail when accessing them by name.

Now, the parameters are *defined* in the pipeline using the keyword `parameters`, but *are accessed* using the keyword `params`, e.g.:

```
pipeline {
    agent  any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'BUNDLE_NAME', defaultValue: '', description: '')
        string(name: 'BUNDLE_VERSION', defaultValue: '', description: '')
    }

    stages {
        stage('A') {
            steps {
                script {
                    println "BUNDLE_NAME is ${params.BUNDLE_NAME}"
                    println "BUNDLE_VERSION is " + params.BUNDLE_VERSION
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to use the default value. there is no easy/nicer way to do it? sounds like simple functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "I prefer not to use the default value"?

Comment: I meant there are some groovy functions which suppose to handle empty fields

Comment: Maybe `if(params.BUNDLE_VERSION == "") { ... }` would help.